# Why am I forced to enter a title for the registration confirmation page even if I don't use it?

Tags: civievent

I have to manually enter a title for the registration confirmation page, even if I say I do not want a confirmation page.

"Please enter a Title for the registration Confirmation Page"

I recall this field used to be prefilled, now its blank at default.

I was able to replicate in demo master. Wordpress.

Comment: Yeah I've noticed this too it seems weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have submitted a [PR that fixes this issue](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/25410) (which was a recent regression).